# How to show snack bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, for-loop, textfield, messenger, snackbar

I am developing flutter calculator app
And when I am getting numbers from textfields just I want to show snackbar  if the one of the textfield is empty or
If both of them are empty after clicking a button if they are not empty I am showing the sum result and in this case I don't have any problem
And to be more specific I am adding a picture of my simple app

I tried showsnakbarmassenger.of(context).showsnackbare and other codes after reading documentation and watching videos in YouTube but I got error no scaffold messenger widget found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are deprecated APIs, currently you can show a snackBar with this:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("example text")));
```

Comment: I have written the above code that you have written but it got error (no scaffold messenger found).